# What do you do if you are being hacked by something coming from a supposedly legitimate IP address such as from Google?

Tags: security, honeypot

Earlier today I was prompted to use a CAPTCHA — because of suspicious search activity — when doing a Google search, So I assumed either a PC on my network had a virus or something.

After poking around I noticed — from my router logs—that there were tons of connections to my Raspberry Pi that I had set up as a web server — port forwarded to 80 and 22 — so I pulled the card, turned off that port forward and re-imaged it this time as a “[honey pot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing))” and the results are very interesting

The honey pot is reporting that there are successful attempts to log in with the username/pass combination `pi`/`raspberry`, and logs the IP’s — these are coming in almost every second — and some of the IP’s when I investigate are supposed to be Google’s IP.

So I don’t know, are they doing, if it is supposed “[white hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security))” stuff, or whatever. It seems like that is an illegal intrusion. They aren’t doing anything after they log in.

Here is an example IP address: `23.236.57.199`

Comment: Take a look at this, specifically the comment: http://whois.domaintools.com/23.236.57.199

Comment: If you properly secure the device this should not concern you. This actually is the answer to the question: What to do? Secure the device.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit because the focus is what to do if you know you are being attacked, rather than how to prevent it... which I think is documented lots of places...

Comment: I hope you're not using the `pi/raspberry` combination on anything else besides your honeypot. The moment you make it accessible from outside it should have something more decent than that.

Comment: @mast pi is only honeypot; at some point I will just pull the logs, get a new IP and re-image it

Comment: @usr - of course it should concern you. While this isn't a full DoS, ~100k requests per day is still taxing for the server, and could easily push someone over the limit of their hostings bandwidth.

Comment: It does not answer your question "what to do" but it could give some context: there are services like https://www.shodan.io/ that do just that, they search for vulnerable services like the ones with default credentials and index them. They supposedly do nothing else, just index them. Maybe something similar happened to you.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> So I don’t know, are they doing, if it is supposed “[white hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security))”
>   stuff, or whatever. It seems like that is an illegal intrusion. They
>   aren’t doing anything after they log in.

You are assuming Google themselves are “attacking” your server, when the reality is Google also provides web hosting and application hosting services to most anyone who pays to use them. So a user using those services could have a script/program in place that is doing the “hacking.”

Doing a [reverse DNS record (PTR) lookup on `23.236.57.199`](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3A23.236.57.199&run=toolpage) further confirms this idea:

```
199.57.236.23.bc.googleusercontent.com
```

You can check this—on your own—from the command line in Mac OS X or Linux like this:

```
dig -x 23.236.57.199 +nocomments +noquestion +noauthority +noadditional +nostats
```

And the result I get from the command line in Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -x 23.236.57.199 +nocomments +noquestion +noauthority +noadditional +nostats
;; global options: +cmd
199.57.236.23.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN    PTR 199.57.236.23.bc.googleusercontent.com.
```

Or you could use just `+short` to truly get only the core response answer like this:

```
dig -x 23.236.57.199 +short
```

Which would return:

```
199.57.236.23.bc.googleusercontent.com.
```

The base domain name of `googleusercontent.com` clearly is what it says it is, “Google User Content” which is known to be connected to the [Google App Engine “Platform as a Service” product](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs). And that allows any user to create and deploy code in Python, Java, PHP & Go applications to their service.

If you feel these accesses are malicious, you can [report suspected abuse to Google directly via this page](https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report?hl=en). Be sure to include your raw log data so Google staff can see exactly what you are seeing.

Past any of that, [this Stack Overflow answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19669792) how one can go about getting a list of IP addresses connected to the `googleusercontent.com` domain name. Could be useful if you want to filter “Google User Content” accesses from other system accesses.

Answer (score 42):

The following information obtained using the command `whois 23.236.57.199` explains what you need to do:

```
Comment:        *** The IP addresses under this Org-ID are in use by Google Cloud customers ***
Comment:        
Comment:        Please direct all abuse and legal complaints regarding these addresses to the
Comment:        GC Abuse desk (google-cloud-compliance@google.com).  Complaints sent to 
Comment:        any other POC will be ignored.
```